# NIntegrate 2D highly oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration, machine-precision

I am trying to integrate a function, and the error I get is greater than the result.

So I need to calculate

```
NIntegrate[osc[n,L,u,x]*f1[u, x]/f2[u, x], {u, 0, 1}, {x, 1, inf}]
```

where

```
f1[u_,x_] := u(1-u) ( 1-Cos[x]-x Sin[x] )

f2[u_,x_] := (1-u)^2 x^2 + 2u(1-u) x Sin[x] + 2( 1-Cos[x] ) u^2
```

and

```
osc[n_,L_,u_,x_]:= Exp[-I u x(n+L)+2I n ArcTan[(u(1-Cos[x]))/(u Sin[x]+x(1-u))]]
```

Here, `n` and `L` are parameters: `n` is an integer (1, 2, 3, …), and `L` is real > 0

The best I got was by using `Method -> "LevinRule"`:

For example, by using

```
nn=1; LL = 1;
```

I get

```
int[n_,L_,u_,x_] := osc[n,L,u,x]*f1[u, x]/f2[u, x];
inf = Infinity;
NIntegrate[ int[nn, LL, u, x], {u, 0, 1}, {x, 1, inf}, Method -> 
   {"LevinRule", "Kernel" -> osc[nn, LL, u, x]}]

(* -0.0741726 + 0.0851585 I *)
```

with an error of `0.18027814`

Note that the error is greater than the result.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The option `WorkingPrecision` might help.

Comment: What are `int[]` and `inf`?

Comment: Sorry, int[n,L,u,x]=osc[n,L,u,x]*f1[u, x]/f2[u, x], and inf= infinity

Comment: @Jinxed Thanks Jinxed: increasing WorkingPrecision just give me more digit numbers but doesn’t change the results while spending more time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks Michael. You are right we have singularity at u==1 and cos(x)==1, because in that cases f2[nn,LL,u,x]==0.

I’m sure the integral have to be finite, so is just a matter of how to deal with it. 

I have tried the Exclusions option to avoid the integrand is evaluated at such singular points and this improves the results for a finite x intervale but Mathematica crashes when trying to integrate up to infinity.

Comment: Here’s what I get:

**nn = 1; LL = 1; xmin = 1 Pi; xmax = 5 Pi;**

**NIntegrate[ int[nn, LL, u, x], {u, 0, 1}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 Exclusions -> Cos[x] == 1,  Method -> {“LevinRule", "Kernel" -> osc[nn, LL, u, x]}]**

and 

**NIntegrate[ int[nn, LL, u, x], {u, 0, 1}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
 Exclusions -> u == 1,  Method -> {“LevinRule", "Kernel" -> osc[nn, LL, u, x]}]**

gives the same result

(* -0.0436609 + 0.0635504 I, error = 0.00360909 *)

Comment: But, when putting the exclusion explicitly into the interval we get the same result with a better error

**NIntegrate[ int[nn, LL, u, x], {u, 0, 1}, {x, xmin, 2Pi, 4Pi, xmax}, 
  Method -> {“LevinRule", "Kernel" -> osc[nn, LL, u, x]}]**

(* error= 0.00296418 *)

The matter is how to do it for a large interval, say: for 30 Pi <x< 50 Pi, without having to exclude each point at hand.

Comment: Hope your are happy with my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that infinitely many, semi periodic singularities makes for a very difficult integral.  If you could find a substitution that would tame all the singularities at once, you could probably succeed in truly taming this integral.

I agree with the OP that each singularity is integrable, but one has also to wonder whether the sum of the infinitely many singularities exists.  My feeling is that it does.  Even though the magnitude of the integrand looks like it falls off as $1/x$, the oscillatory nature of the function does not rule out convergence, and the numerical calculations I get stay around `0.08(6) + 0.08(1) I`, not too far from the OP's result.

My thought was that since the singularities occur as $u \rightarrow 1^-$, $x \rightarrow 2 \pi n^-$, $n$ an integer, we might divide the infinite strip `{u, 0, 1}, {x, 0, Infinity}` into infinitely many rectangles `{u, 0, 1}, {x, 2 Pi n, 2 Pi + 2 Pi n}` and sum the integrals.  (One has to subtract the integral over `{u, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}` to get the OP's integral, of course.)  A singularity occurs only in one corner of each rectangle.  This suggests that using [Duffy's coordinates](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#738848244) might be useful.  The substitution transforms a singularity at a corner to one along an edge.  If the singularity is of the right type, it can be quite effective.  In this case, it helps, but the singularity persists to be a nuisance. However, the  [IMT singularity handler](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#159907828) helps, at least to the extent that with a higher working precision, the integral can be computed with the desired precision.

Summing the integrals over the rectangles can be done with [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSum.html).  This means approximating the sum using approximate terms.  I'm not real sure what the compounding of the error implies.  Given that all terms were computed with a relative precision of `MachinePrecision/2` digits and the real and imaginary parts of the terms all have the same sign (except the imaginary part of the first term), the sum should be nearly as good as `NSum` usually calculates, I suppose.

Another strategy I used was to isolate the singularity in the corner.  Away from the corner `NIntegrate` can accurately compute the integral with the `"LevinRule"` method.  Luckily the singularity can be predicted to lie in the rectangle `{u, 1 - 1/Max[n, 1]/4, 1}, {x, 3 Pi/2 + 2 Pi n, 2 Pi + 2 Pi n}`.  We just have to figure out how to integrate this singularity.

For some reason `Method -> {"DuffyCoordinates", "Corners" -> {{1, 1}}}` was insufficient to compute the integrals with the desired precision.  But the `NIntegrate` tutorial linked above includes code for manually performing the substitution.  We can then call `NIntegrate` specifying the singularity handler `"SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"`, which finally seems to conquer the problem.

So finally, here is the code that implements the above strategy.  The function `DuffyCoordinates` is given in [this section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#354695682) of the `NItegrate` tutorial.  I would include it, but I'm not sure about copyright restrictions.  Warning: It takes a long time, about a minute or so per rectangle; hence the results are memoized. `Print` statements are included for the impatient. The singular integral **always** gives a singularity warning `NIntegrate::slwcon`, so I supressed it with `Quiet`.

```
ClearAll[intpart7, f1, f2, osc, int];

(* OP's definitions *)
f1[u_, x_] := u (1 - u) (1 - Cos[x] - x Sin[x])
f2[u_, x_] := (1 - u)^2 x^2 + 2 u (1 - u) x Sin[x] + 2 (1 - Cos[x]) u^2
osc[n_, L_, u_, x_] := 
 Exp[-I u x (n + L) + 2 I n ArcTan[(u (1 - Cos[x]))/(u Sin[x] + x (1 - u))]]
nn = 1; LL = 1;
int[u_, x_] := osc[nn, LL, u, x]*f1[u, x]/f2[u, x]

(* integrates over the n-th rectangle *)
intpart7[n_Integer] := Block[{x, u},
   Print[n];
   intpart7[n] = (* memoize for reuse *)
    NIntegrate[            (* nonsingular integral *)
      Boole[0 <= u <= 1 - 0.25/Max[n, 1] || 2 Pi n <= x <= 2 Pi n + 3 Pi/2]*int[u, x],
      {u, 0, 1}, {x, 2 Pi n, 2 Pi + 2 Pi n},
      MaxRecursion -> 25, 
      Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
        Method -> {"LevinRule", "Kernel" -> osc[nn, LL, u, x]}}] +
     Quiet[Print["."];
      NIntegrate @@ Join[  (* singular part *)
        DuffyCoordinates[
         int[u, x], {u, 1 - 1/Max[n, 1]/4, 1},
         {x, 3 Pi/2 + 2 Pi n, 2 Pi + 2 Pi n}, {1, 1}],
        {PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
         MaxRecursion -> 25, 
         Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}}
        ], NIntegrate::slwcon]
   ];
```

**Grand result**

```
intzero = NIntegrate[int[u, x], {u, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
(sum = NSum[intpart7[n], {n, 0, Infinity}]) // AbsoluteTiming
sum - intzero
(*
  -0.0751088 + 0.0187646 I                (* integral 0 < x < 1 *)
  {1891.108293, -0.161177 + 0.0992955 I}  (* {time, sum} *)

  -0.0860682 + 0.0805309 I                (* final integral *)
*)
```

*No error estimate warnings!*

Remark: The computed terms may be inspected with `? intpart7` or `DownValues[intpart7]`.  The indices `n` computed are

```
Cases[DownValues[intpart7], HoldPattern[intpart7[n_Integer]] :> n, Infinity]
(*
  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
   19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 30, 93305, 93306, 93307}
*)
```

**Accuracy of results**

We can see that using more terms in the estimation by `NSum` tends to increase the magnitude of the result, but by less and less.  I let this run, while I was doing other stuff. It probably takes a total of two hours, including the time above.  `NSum` does not seem to estimate the tail of the sum very accurately.  It's possible that it diverges very slowly, but the OP seems to think it converges.  I have not thought very much about it.

```
seq = Table[NSum[intpart7[n], {n, 0, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> n] - intzero, {n, 15, 100, 10}]
(*
{-0.0860682 + 0.0805309 I,
 -0.0861501 + 0.0805336 I,
 -0.0860646 + 0.0805342 I,
 -0.0861001 + 0.0805403 I,
 -0.0861384 + 0.080535 I,
 -0.0861612 + 0.0805338 I,
 -0.0861782 + 0.080533 I,
 -0.0861947 + 0.080534 I,
 -0.0862018 + 0.0805343 I}
*)

ListLinePlot[Abs@Differences@seq, DataRange -> {15, 95}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Visualization of the Duffy transformation**

The plots below show the real and imaginary parts of the integrand in the singular corner of the domain for `n = 10` before and after the substitution of Duffy's coordinates.  One can see that the singularity is moved to the edge as required by the `"IMT"` singularity handler.

```
Block[{n = 10, style, fn},
 {style[Re], style[Im]} = 
  Take["DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", Plot3D]), 2];
 fn["int"] = {##} &;
 fn["Duffy"] = {First@DuffyCoordinates[##], {u, 0, 1/n}, {x, 1 - 2/n, 1}} &;
 GraphicsGrid@
  Table[Plot3D[part[#1], #2, #3, PlotRange -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
      PlotPoints -> 35, PlotStyle -> style[part], 
      AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> part[f]] & @@ 
    fn[f] @@ {int[u, x], {u, 1 - 1/Max[n, 1]/4, 1}, {x, 3 Pi/2 + 2 Pi n, 2 Pi + 2 Pi n}, {1, 1}},
   {part, {Re, Im}}, {f, {"int", "Duffy"}}
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Michael Thanks a lot! Your help and commitment really motives me to also help other people. I have tested your program and it works perfectly. I will use it to compute a set of integrals that have the same behavior. When finished I'd like to let you now (if you don't bother).

Comment: @OmarAlbertoRoldanGarcia You're welcome.  Best of luck with the rest of your project.  Feel free to let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the findings so far, and just need help on dynamically creating the exclusions, you might want to proceed with the following index-generation code:

```
DeleteDuplicates@{#1,#2,Sequence@@Range[Ceiling[#2,2\[Pi]],Floor[#3,2\[Pi]],2\[Pi]],#3}&
```

which can be called with the variable and its lower and upper bounds like so, e.g.:

```
DeleteDuplicates@{#1,#2,Sequence@@Range[Ceiling[#2,2\[Pi]],Floor[#3,2\[Pi]],2\[Pi]],#3}&[x,1,10]
```

So, your `NIntegrate` becomes:

```
NIntegrate[int[nn, LL, u, x], {u, 0, 1},
  DeleteDuplicates@{#1,#2,
  Sequence@@Range[Ceiling[#2,2\[Pi]],Floor[#3,2\[Pi]],2\[Pi]],#3}&[x,xmin,xmax],
  Method->{"LevinRule", "Kernel"->osc[nn,LL,u,x]}]
```

Comment: Thanks Jinxed, your tips have been very useful! I took me a little long to answer because I'm on a trip. The errors have indeed diminished.

Comment: @OmarAlbertoRoldanGarcia: You are very welcome!